# Spring Boot : Create a bean only if its dependencies exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies

I have a project in Spring Boot 1.5.2. I have a bean and I would like to create it only if all its dependencies are created. I tested Spring autoconfiguration without success and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. The last solution works. I am wondering what is the better way to do it. Thanks.

**Edit**

I tested Spring autoconfiguration with the below class without success. My bean not be created :

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(value = JavaMailSender.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MailAutoConfiguration {
@Bean
    public MyMailSender createMyMailSender() {
    return new MyMailSender();
    }
}
```

MailAutoConfiguration and MyMailSender are in the same package

**Edit**

I found my problem. I had not seen this constraint :

```
Auto-configurations have to be loaded that way only. Make sure that they
are defined in a specific package space and that they are never the target of
component scan in particular.
```

I can use now @ConditionalOnBean

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you have a look at the different `@Conditional` annotations?

Comment: Seconded @dunni, I would think that [@ConditionalOnBean](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) would go a long way.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnBean` is the better way, IMO. @atoua, perhaps you could show what you tried without success?

Comment: Could you show us what you have done to fix it? Thanks.